# CLLocationManager: Requesting higher permissions

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-location

CLLocationManager has two methods to request permissions:

```
requestWhenInUseAuthorization
requestAlwaysAuthorization
```

However, these methods do nothing if the current authorization status is anything other than "kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined". I would like my application to start by only prompting users for location permission when the application is in use and only request higher permissions if the user takes an actions that requires it. The issue is when I attempt to request for higher permissions, the authorization state has already been determined and thus nothing happens. Is it possible to still prompt users for higher permissions instead of having to force them to go to the settings pages to change permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, according to the CLLocationManager docs you can't request permissions if you already have any permission granted.  Which means you can't change from WhenInUse to Always. You have to decide which one you want when you first request permission.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 8 you have to manage authorizations in the Poject>info file with

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

as keys and the value will be the message you show.

Comment: These description key are required for the alert to ever appear. The issue I am having is that after the user allows InUseAuthorization, I can no longer request AlwaysAuthentication even if the description key is set because the authentication state has been determined.

Comment: Sorry I must been lost, why would you request higher permission when the user already allowed you inUse permission?

Comment: For my application, I have most users viewing pins on a map, which can be placed by other users. I decide what pins to display based on how far they are from the user. (Thus most users only need InUseAuthorization.) However, some users can attach a pin to themselves, which should change location when they move. For this, I need AlwaysAuthentication because I would like the pin to follow them even when the application is closed, however most users do not need this AlwaysAuthentication.

Comment: I still don't see why you need Always authorization.  You can't move the pin while the app is closed anyway, you update the pin location when the app starts up.  If you are not using significant location change or region monitoring then you don't need Always authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is very clear both in the docs and in the WWDC 2014 videos: you can't change location services authorization level. Once your app has received When In Use authorization, it cannot obtain Always authorization. If any feature of your app needs Always authorization then you should have asked for Always authentication from the start.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11 you are even encouraged to first ask for `.whenInUse` Permission and then escalate later to `.always`.

See [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization):

> In iOS 11 and later, if you initially requested only when-in-use authorization, you can call the requestAlwaysAuthorization() method at a later time (as shown in Listing 2) to escalate your app's authorization level.